# Here Android SDK - Speed camera warnings when not navigating

Tags: android, here-api

We'd like to warn our users of of the 'safety spots' even when the navigation is not started by startNavigation. Whenever navigation is not on, we're in the startTracking -mode in our app.

Is it possible to warn the users of speed cameras (e.g. 500 m before the spot) in 'tracking' mode? Can we get callbacks to SafetySpotListener or can we achieve this somehow else?

When navigation is on, the warnings are working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's available only for navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hope to see this feature soon :).